# Detecting brief break in connection with AVPlayerItem

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, key-value-observing

If I start this stream and then turn wifi off, "playbackBufferEmpty" is fired and I can respond by attempting to restart the stream. However if I turn wifi off and back on again straight away, the stream stops playing but none of the observers are triggered.

```
- (void)restartStream
{
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    NSLog(@"Removing Observers");
    [self.radioStream removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
    [self.radioStream removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata"];
    [self.radioStream removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty"];
    [self.radioStream removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"];
    NSLog(@"Creating New AVPlayerItem");
    self.radioStream = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mystream.com"]];
    [self.radioStream addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
    [self.radioStream addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    [self.radioStream addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    [self.radioStream addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    NSLog(@"Playing radioPlayer with new AVPlayerItem");
    self.radioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.radioStream];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with the simulator. "status" or "playbackBufferEmpty" are triggered on the device.